# Inserting several items from array to database with `foreach`

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, json

I want to insert several items from an array into a database with `foreach`. I get an error 
`Message: Undefined offset`. Can someone help me figure out what's causing it?

error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Line Number: 127

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Line Number: 128

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Line Number: 129
```

php:

```
<?php

$guide_input = $this->input->post('guide');
$airline_input = $this->input->post('airline');

$name_r_input = $this->input->post('name_r');
$units_input = $this->input->post('units');
$price_change_input = $this->input->post('price_change');

$guide = array();
$airline = array();
$date_go = array();
$date_back = array();
$residence = array();
foreach ($guide_input as $idx => $name) {
    $guide[] = array(
        'name_guide' => $guide_input[$idx], //Line Number: 121
    );
    $airline[] = array(
        'name_airline' => $airline_input[$idx], //Line Number: 124
    );
    $residence[] = array(
        'name_r' => $name_r_input[$idx], //Line Number: 127
        'units' => $units_input[$idx], //Line Number: 128
        'price_change' => $price_change_input[$idx], //Line Number: 128
    );
};
$data = array(
    'json1' => json_encode($residence),
    'json2' => json_encode($airline),
    'json3' => json_encode($guide),
);

$this->db->insert(tableName, $data);
```

Comment: Did you try your code? Did it work? If not, what didn't work like you expected? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes, i get error: `Message: Undefined offset`

Comment: Please edit your post and add the **exact** error message you receive. **Exact**, because it will make it much easier for someone to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: @Ken White, thanks, i edit post and put error and line it. please see and help me?

Comment: I when change this line `foreach($guide_input as $idx=>$name){` to `foreach($name_r_input as $idx=>$name){` , same error display for lines `121` & `124`

Answer (score 1):

above code assumes that all input arrays like $airline_input, $date_go_input and so on.. will have the same number of elements as $guide_input in them. My guess is they dont.

For the code to be correct and run without errors yu should check:

```
count($guide_input) == count($airline_input)
&& count($guide_input) == count($date_go_input)
// ... and so on... //
```

Comment: With her update of the exact error information, it looks more like one or more of the arrays might be empty or null. I'm not a php programmer, though, so I could be all wrong. :)

Comment: I when change this line `foreach($guide_input as $idx=>$name){` to `foreach($name_r_input as $idx=>$name){` , same error display for lines `121` & `124` see this lines in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check `guide_input`, `airline_input`, and so on. Every arrays has same keys?

Comment: How should check they for array?

Comment: I think you can simply print out them: `print_r(guide_input)` (if you don't use any debugging tool).